# How does TLS 1.3 sign key exchange?

Tags: diffie-hellman, tls, pki

From this site: https://tls13.ulfheim.net/ and from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-2 I can't find the part in which the exchange of keys is signed, isn't one of the parties "key_share" supposed to be signed using the server certificate's keys?

For example this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsGeV.png

In the image above I can only see the x25519 which from what I have seen is ECDH (source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519)
but is missing the authentication ECDH with RSA or ECDSA, unless it isn't specified under the assumption that anonymous key exchange isn't an option in TLS 1.3.

Comment: Have you checked `CertificateVerify` in that document? It authenticates the entire handshake, and that obviously *includes* the key exchange. It certainly doesn't use encryption, that's only used in TLS 1.2 RSA_ cipher suites (i.e. those that do not use key agreement), and then the master secret is encrypted. Instead it uses signature generation.

Comment: I was looking into the handshake itself to see where it's authenticated, and by encrypted I meant signed. Thank you! I was looking for it everywhere when it was right in front of me :)